# i`m a React beginner and function setState() is not working, and i need your help guys

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently studying React and tried to make To-do list. Below is the source code.

I want to change the state "display" of the Frame component by clicking the button. I found out that the handler I `addEventListener'd` to the button element worked, but the state display never changed and even there are no errors on console. Why?

## Frame Component

```js
class Frame extends Component {
  state = {
    list: ["왜", "안돼냐"],
    display: "before!!!",
  };

  registerHandler = () => {
    this.setState = {
      display: "after",
    };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="frame">
        <h1>To-Do-Lists</h1>
        <h2>{this.state.display}</h2>
        <div className="wrapper">
          <Lists list={this.state.list} />
        </div>

        <div className="action">
          <Button name="Register" onClick={this.registerHandler} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Frame;
```

## Button 관련 부분

```js
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

const button = (props) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <button onClick={props.onClick} className="action button">
        {props.name}
      </button>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default button;
```

Comment: Check this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-does-setstate-do) from React documentation. It might be useful

Answer (score 1):

Mby you trying to set `this.setState` equal to something, try use it like this `this.setState({})`